# Esc key acts like reset button in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having two text boxes with a reset and a submit button. The reset button is working fine.  But when i enter something in those two text boxes and press esc, the values gets disappeared. Event acts like a reset button. I am not sure how to control it. Much appreciate your help... Thanks...

```
<input type="text" name="" /> <input type="text" name="" /> 

<input type="button" value="Search" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="" />
<input type="text" name="" />
input type="button" value="Search" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />

Comment: You'll have to provide more code than that.

Comment: @Riyas see this once, I couldn't find any reset functionality when I press esc http://jsfiddle.net/xgTxK/1/

Comment: Any JavaScript included in your page?

Comment: @Riyas: when you provide code, write it in the question, not in comments

Comment: @Pravallika69 Check your code in IE. Esc acts as a reset button. Not in other browsers.

Comment: @Riyas check the solution once, I have provided this solution in the answer section

Answer (score 3):

It's working fine in all browsers http://jsfiddle.net/xgTxK/2/

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode==27){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

add above script in your code to prevent default functionality

Comment: Maybe it's better to `return false;`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is consistent across all browsers, but I've noticed esc button will typically reset the text typed in a text input, but only while still focused within the text input. Or to put another way, esc will reset the text if the onchange event hasn't occured yet.

And I would assume to prevent this would need to use JavaScript to capture the key events within the input and prevent the default behavior.